# Trouble getting Mocha, node.js and WebStorm to work with each other

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webstorm, ts-node

I have been following the instructions to install Mocha with WebStorm found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/testing-javascript-with-mocha.html#d194239e92

I have set the configurations to run files that match the pattern: `**/*.spec.js`

```
node interpreter: /usr/bin/node
working directory:/home/web/app
mocha package:/home/web/app/node_modules/mocha
```

I am writing in TypeScript which is converted to ES6, the output of which is what I'm attempting to test. However I get this error which I don't understand and so don't really know where to begin looking to resolve.

I don't understand why it is looking for "ts-node", considering it's only supposed to look for "spec.js" files. and past that, I don't understand why the folder it is looking for in ts-node is missing. I have uninstalled then re-installed ts-node a couple times, neither of which yielded the sought after folder... I have no clue as to how to proceed or even what further information is needed to help resolve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated. I just want to test my application and this is proving to be a real headache.

Here is the error:

> /usr/bin/node /home/web/app/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --ui bdd
>   --reporter /opt/webstorm/ws/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js
>   **/*.spec.js TypeError: The specified path does not exist: /home/web/app/node_modules/ts-node/tests
>       at resolveSync (/home/web/app/node_modules/ts-node/node_modules/tsconfig/src/tsconfig.ts:72:9)
>       at Object.loadSync (/home/web/app/node_modules/ts-node/node_modules/tsconfig/src/tsconfig.ts:140:16)
>       at readConfig (/home/web/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:418:18)
>       at Object.register (/home/web/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:176:18)
>       at Suite. (/home/web/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.spec.ts:190:5)
>       at Object.create (/home/web/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:114:19)
>       at context.describe.context.context (/home/web/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:44:27)
>       at Suite. (/home/web/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.spec.ts:189:3)
>       at Object.create (/home/web/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:114:19)
>       at context.describe.context.context (/home/web/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:44:27)
>       at Object. (/home/web/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.spec.ts:13:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at /home/web/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:230:27
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/web/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:227:14)
>       at Mocha.run (/home/web/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:495:10)
>       at Object. (/home/web/app/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:460:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, my path was from the root of my project, which contained node_modules, and so the node_modules directory was being tested, causing errors from tests inside the ts-node folder. the fix was to exclude node_modules directory from the specified path for test modules.